# What is the probability that tomorrow it will not rain nor the dawn be cloudy, if you know that these two events are independent?

Tags: probability

I have this statement:

> The probability that it will rain tomorrow is $0.25$ and the
>   probability of cloudy dawn is $0.3$.
>
> What is the probability that tomorrow it will not rain nor the dawn be cloudy,
>   if you know that these two events are independent?

My attempt was:

Let $L$ the probability of rain, let $C$ the probability that it is a cloudy day.

First,  $P(L \cap C) = P(L)\cdot P(C)$ since they are independent.

I need the probability of $P(L)^c \cap P(C)^c$, i.e that it does not rain and that at the same time, it is not a cloudy day. According to Morgan's law it is equal to $P(L \cup C)^c$. Therefore the probability is equal to $1 - \underbrace{(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{10} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{10})}_{P(L \cup C)} = 0.525$

But according to the guide, the correct answer must be $0.925$. What is wrong with my development? Thanks in advance.

The explanation of the guide was:

> If the events are independent, then it rains and dawns cloudy has
>   probability $0,25 · 0,30 = 0,075$ , then the probability that it will
>   not be cloudy or new equals $1 - 0.075 = 0.925$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your derivation is correct. Does the guide include how it got its solution, or is it just the answers?

Comment: Your calculation is correct ... the answer book is wrong

Comment: Shaun, thanks for that advice, I'll read that.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Of course, i'll edit with that information.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Already edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented on already, your derivation is correct.

The book's error is that it only finds the probability it will not be simultaneously rainy and cloudy (i.e. it gives $1 - P(L \cap C)$). It does not account for each event happening individually, which would be $1 - P(L \cup C)$ as you have noticed.